# FTP corrupting subsequent aiff files from old mac to new mac

Tags: mac, ftp

This is a bizarre one.

So I am trying to xfer files from an old mac to a new mac, but the old one has no USB, no firewire, just ethernet. So I hooked it up the the network, downloaded fetch and started a FTP server.

The first file transfers fine, but all the subsequent ones are corrupted.

I can reconnect and transfer a new file and it works, but every file afterwards is corrupted, somehow. I tried forcing binary transfer, but that didn't help.

Any ideas? From System 8.6 > Osx 10.7.5

Comment: Try using sftp or rsync instead of ftp.

Comment: good idea, except there ain't no rsync on a 860x0 mac. ;)